# Why does html helper beginform format the way displayed

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does adding the BeginForm tag at the top show the 'Delete' button beside the Edit and Details section? Code and Image attached.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Employee", new { id = item.EmployeeID}))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeID }) |
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" 
                       onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete user @item.Name');"   />

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: because `input type="submit"` is a button, not a link like `edit` is. add a class to your input and create a css style to have it look how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

`input type = submit` means a button.. you can customize the style of the button however you like with classes but Edit and Details can be customized as links bc they redirect you to another page.